# Statistical interpretation of diagonal of Cholesky decomposition?

Tags: regression, covariance, cholesky-decomposition

Given a set of $m$ examples $x$ arranged as rows in $m\times n$ data matrix X, consider Cholesky decomposition of covariance matrix $X'X$.

Is there a statistical interpretation of diagonal entries of Cholesky, or equivalently of $D$ in LDLt decomposition of covariance?

$$X'X=LDL'$$

There's an interpretation of $L$ in terms of coefficients of linear model predicting $i$th coordinate of $x$ from all previous ones, hence we can estimate entries of $L$ approximately by fitting linear models to subsets of data. **Is there an analogous way to estimate $D$ approximately?**

Some related statistical interpretations:

Use least-squares to fit a *one-sided* auto-regressive model predicting $i$th coordinate of $x$ from coordinates $j<i$, and arrange these coefficients as entries of $\phi$ so that $x.\phi$ predicts $x$ . We can extract entries of $L$ from $\phi$ using the following:
$$\phi = I - (L^{-1})^{T}$$

Similarly, we can estimate entries of $(X'X)^{-1}$ by fitting *two-sided* autoregressive models of $x$, predicting $i$th coordinate $x_i$ from coordinates $x_j, j\ne i$.

Arrange coefficients of these models as entries of $B$. Let $R=X-XB$ indicate the residuals left over after subtracting predictions of this model from X. Diagonal entries of inverse of $X$ have interpretation in terms of per-feature residual norms squared:

$$\text{diag}((X'X)^{-1})=\frac{1}{\text{diag}(R'R)}$$

If we let $D_2=(X'X)^{-1}_d$ with $_d$ notation indicating that all off-diagonal terms are set to zero, then inverse of $(X'X)$ has interpretation in terms of predictive coefficients $B$

$$(X'X)^{-1} = (I-B)D_2$$

Plugging in statistical interpretation of $D_2$ we can define inverse of $X'X$ purely in terms of coefficients $B$ which could be estimated from data.

$$(X'X)^{-1} = (I-B)[((X-BX)'(X-BX))_d]^{-1}$$

We can similarly write inverse of $X'X$ in terms of coefficients of one-sided linear models arranged as $\phi$:

$$(X'X)^{-1} = (I-\phi)'D^{-1}(I-\phi)$$

Unlike inverse in terms of two-sided autoregressive model $B$, using one-sided autoregressive model $\phi$ involves matrix $D$ from $LDL'$ decomposition, so it's not directly usable without statistical way to estimate $D$. Having a way to estimate $D$ from data would give a way to

1. Formulate matrix inverse in terms of one-sided autoregressive model coefficients
2. Get an iterative algorithm for approximating Cholesky decomposition of covariance $X'X$ or precision matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$

([notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/whitening_inverse_transposed.nb))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the $X_i$ variables follow a normal distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and
$$\Sigma = LDL'$$
then the diagonal elements of $D$ are the conditional variances of each $X_i$ conditional on $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}$.
And, as you have already said, the elements of the $i$th row of $L$ give the regression coefficients of $X_i$ on $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}$.

More generally, if the $X_i$ are not normally distributed, then the elements of $L$ define the best linear predictor for $X_i$ based on $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}$ and the diagonal elements of $D$ give the variances of the residuals from these linear regressions.
In other words, the elements of $D$ gives the variance of each $X_i$ not explained by linear regression on $X_1,\ldots,X_{i-1}$.

In your question, you are computing the LDL decomposition not of a covariance matrix but of a squared data matrix.
If each column of the data matrix $X$ was mean-corrected, then $X'X$ would be a sample covariance matrix, and the theoretical interpretation for the Cholesky decomposition would hold in an estimated sense.
If the data is not mean-corrected, then $X'X$ is not a covariance matrix and the interpretation does not hold.

The Cholesky decomposition algorithm, when properly coded with forward and backward equations, is a marvelously efficient and stable numerical algorithm that does not require any matrix inversions.
So I am a bit surprised that you are trying to approximate it, especially with equations that look to me to be somewhat inefficient.
There also exist Cholesky algorithms that produce banded $L$ matrices, i.e., which limit the number of previous variables than each $X_i$ depends on.
Banded Cholesky algorithms are appropriate for auto-regressive processes.
I wrote Fortran subroutines to do such things when I was a PhD student back in the 1980s!
If you are dealing with auto-regressive time series, then you could look into state-space models, which can be viewed as an implementation of an LDL Cholesky decomposition for time series.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth reply! I need to divide by covariance matrix, but it's too large to even fit into memory, hence was looking at approximate ways of representing "divide by covariance" operation, banded Cholesky may be useful here, thanks for the tip

Comment: You might also want to look at algorithms based on sparse precision matrices ...